# POST HTTP Angular 2

Tags: html, go, angular2-forms

I have problem with POST. I wanna upload text and image on Golang Server. 
This repository of project: https://github.com/KorobkaVadim/Family-Tree
This form https://github.com/KorobkaVadim/Family-Tree/tree/master/Angular/app/todo-form

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Don`t upload text and image.

Comment: I`m Junior)) Plese more deteils.

Comment: I guess you are missing `enctype=multipart/form-data` in your `<form>` tag